# mongoose: [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client

Tags: node.js, typescript, mongodb, mongoose

I'm not a backend developer but I know my way around express and NodeJS. This is the first time I'm working with MongoDB and I have been stuck on this problem even though there are multiple questions and answers to this similar question but none worked for me.

I understand that this error usually occurs when you are sending multiple responses to the client for a single request. Here is my code:

```
app.post('/myapitest', (req, res) => {
    switch (req.headers['type']) {
        case MY_TYPE.A:

            const connection_string = 'My MongoDB instance link;

            if (connection_string) {

                mongoose.connect(connection_string as string);
                mongoose.connection.once('connected', () => {
                    mongoose.connection.db.listCollections().toArray().then((collections) => {
                        mongoose.connection.close(() => {
                            return res.status(200).json(collections);
                        });
                    }).catch((err) => {
                        mongoose.connection.close(() => {
                            return res.status(400).json({ error: err.message, message: 'looks like something is wrong with connecting to the mongodb' });
                        });
                    });
                })
            } else {
                return res.status(401).send('POST request failed because connection_string is missing in headers or invalid.');
            }
            break;
        default:
            res.status(400).send('POST request failed because type is missing in headers or not supported.');
            break;
    }
```

As per my code above, I know it's not going to send multiple responses. I'm testing from the postman, when I start the project and send the request it gets the response successfully from MongoDB. Then without stopping the program if I send the request again I get the **[ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client** error.

Comment: You shouldn't create Mongoose connections ad hoc, inside a request handler. I'm sure there are some tutorial projects out there that will show how to correctly use Mongoose together with Express, try googling for it.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't seem to contain any error.
Please update the `mongoose` version and try again.